# XCode include necessary header files

Tags: xcode, eclipse, xcode4, macros, include

In Eclipse you can press Cntrl + Shift + O and all of the necessary includes will be added to your file automatically.  Is there anything similar to this in XCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. You have to add them yourself.